# Is it possible to replay a SAML request using PostMan?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are using Itfoxtex identity saml2 in our server application.

On my development machine I am trying to replay a SAML assertion response using PostMan up against the application running on my local machine. But I keep getting System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Digest-bekræftelsen kunne ikke fuldføres for Reference' or in english 'Digest verification failed for Reference'

Is there something I can do in order to bypass this issue for overriding the security aspect? I just want to debug my code, for recreating an issue a user is having.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to use PostMan but it is probably possible.

Instead I usually use a .NET test IdP, you can find a sample [her](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore).